# return a zero for month with zero rows using case extract sql

Tags: sql, oracle

Trying to list last 12 months counting records in each month and want to include months where no record was found to display 0 next to that month name. I tried including another table that would always have at least one record for all 12 months and case extract the month from their but I know I'm doing this wrong. All the research I did, didn't use case extract and I'm looking to keep it if I can.. open to if i cannot.

Current query works and is:

```
select count(RMA.id) "Number of RMAs", case extract(month from 
RMA.RMA_DATE)when 1 then 'January'
when 2 then 'February'
when 3 then 'March'
when 4 then 'April'
when 5 then 'May'
when 6 then 'June'
when 7 then 'July'
when 8 then 'August'
when 9 then 'September'
when 10 then 'October'
when 11 then 'November'
when 12 then 'December'
else 'error'
end, extract(year from RMA.rma_date)
from RMA,
    RMA_DETAIL
where RMA.ID = RMA_DETAIL.RMA_ID And
       RMA.rma_date >= sysdate - 365 And
       RMA_DETAIL.ID <> 3
group by extract(month from RMA.rma_date), extract(year from RMA.rma_date)
order by extract(year from RMA.rma_date), extract(month from RMA.rma_date)
```

results

[image: current query]

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: IQMS manufacturing ERP

Comment: Oracle sorry , production planner first , software CI is my homegrown second job and learning. IQMS is the erp software oracle is the backbone I believe.

Answer (score 0):

## SUM Cases

If you're already fine with identifying the months in the query, it might be worth just summing these up. A **count** can only count what's in the table. If you **sum** up the instances of appearance, you'll get a sum of 0 where your months don't appear. Consider something like this:

```
SELECT
    SUM(CASE WHEN EXTRACT(month from RMA.RMA_DATE) = '1' THEN 1 ELSE 0) AS January
    ,SUM(CASE WHEN EXTRACT(month from RMA.RMA_DATE) = '2' THEN 1 ELSE 0) AS February
    ,SUM(CASE WHEN EXTRACT(month from RMA.RMA_DATE) = '3' THEN 1 ELSE 0) AS March
    ,SUM(CASE WHEN EXTRACT(month from RMA.RMA_DATE) = '4' THEN 1 ELSE 0) AS April
    ,SUM(CASE WHEN EXTRACT(month from RMA.RMA_DATE) = '5' THEN 1 ELSE 0) AS May
    ,SUM(CASE WHEN EXTRACT(month from RMA.RMA_DATE) = '6' THEN 1 ELSE 0) AS June
    ,SUM(CASE WHEN EXTRACT(month from RMA.RMA_DATE) = '7' THEN 1 ELSE 0) AS July
    ,SUM(CASE WHEN EXTRACT(month from RMA.RMA_DATE) = '8' THEN 1 ELSE 0) AS August
    ,SUM(CASE WHEN EXTRACT(month from RMA.RMA_DATE) = '9' THEN 1 ELSE 0) AS September
    ,SUM(CASE WHEN EXTRACT(month from RMA.RMA_DATE) = '10' THEN 1 ELSE 0) AS October
    ,SUM(CASE WHEN EXTRACT(month from RMA.RMA_DATE) = '11' THEN 1 ELSE 0) AS November
    ,SUM(CASE WHEN EXTRACT(month from RMA.RMA_DATE) = '12' THEN 1 ELSE 0) AS December
...
```